# Load Web page in Windows phone Application

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, html

i want to load a web page on my windows phone application but is this possible to change some content of web page while loading? for example, if m developing app for facebook.com  and i want to show 'abcd' on page instead of 'facebook'.  so, changing the content is possible or not?

**NOTE : I AM NOT GOING TO BREAK ANY COPYRIGHT LAW**

Comment: have u tried any code

Comment: Of course it's "possible," the web page is being loaded onto the device and then rendered. If you're running code on the device, you can change it however you want. And it won't violate copyright laws, but it certainly raises serious ethical concerns. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

Technically yes. You can load a webpage inside the app, then modify it after the fact. (If facebook.com, do blank)

But you:

- Cannot do this inside Edge/normal browser, just inside your app.
- Along those lines, can't do anything to trick the user into thinking they are doing anything outside of your app environment.
- Cannot present the content to the user as if it were unmodified, that is deceptive and against Windows Store policy

I suggest reading the Windows Store Policy first to see if your app idea fits within the letter (and the spirit) of the rules: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx